# grails g:field error message

Tags: grails, groovy

How do I customize the error message? It doesn't state in the documentation.

```
<g:field type="number" name="isbn" min="5" max="10" required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the tag reference but in the Grails guide: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#validationAndInternationalization

Comment: what if I do not tie it to a domain class?

Comment: You can tie it to a Command Object also. The definition of the messages follow the same pattern. I don't know how to do it with just the validation of the field tag but I recommend anyway to use a command object.

Comment: Ok, how do I set the message location by the way?

Comment: In grails-app/i18n/messages.properties (for default messages) and grails-app/i18n/messages-{locale}.properties to localize them to specific languages.